# is there a simulator to run my kernel project?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, kernel, simulator

I've got a c++ code of a kernel (just starting with it. So right now, it should just display "Hello, world!") with an array pointing to 0xB8000 (VGA color text mode and CGA-compatible graphics mode). When running it, it says "segmentation fault (core dumped)", which clearly means the display RAM is clearly not accessible by the user (note - I'm in ubuntu). Is there a simulator for running such sort of programs?

(My program is similar to this one -
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1225196/Create-Your-Own-Kernel-In-C-2
all except for that I've written everthing from my understanding, and it successfully compiles)

Comment: That article includes running the code in an emulator. What problems are you having with that?

Comment: See the [OSDev wiki](https://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page), more specifically the section on [QEMU](https://wiki.osdev.org/QEMU), or just read the article you linked in your question (search for `run.sh`)

Comment: when running it with "./a.out" command, it says "segmentation fault (core dumped)" which means VGA RAM is not accessible, so is there a simulator to run the program. brief explanation of my question @Mat ...

Comment: I'll see that one @Botje .

Comment: ok, @botje , just took a look, how do I install QEMU?

Comment: Ubuntu [packages it](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/qemu-system-x86), so just install that. You will need to learn to do research for yourself if you plan to hack on an operating system, otherwise you're in for a lot of frustration.

Comment: make `iso` and use qemu.